# LateInitializationError: Field '_animationControler@549083927' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I am learning Flutter and I faced to this kind of error.

I am trying to solve this by looking for some same situations but I didn't find it yet.
It seems that this is related to Null-safety but I don't know how to solve.

If you know anything please give me any advices

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationControler;
  _play() async {
    setState(() {
      _animationControler.forward();
    });
  }

  _stop() async {
    setState(() {
      _animationControler.stop();
    });
  }

  _reverse() async {
    setState(() {
      _animationControler.reverse();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationControler =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationControler.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title!),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizeTransition(
              sizeFactor: _animationControler,
              child: Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Container(color: Colors.green))),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton:
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _play, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
        FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _stop, child: Icon(Icons.pause)),
        FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _reverse, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. Do you have some more elements that you did not post ?

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild again

Comment: Thank you so much. I just restart the project and it worked fine. the same error occurred and flutter clean worked well too. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As kind people told me flutter clean or restart the project worked for me. Thank you so much kind people.